# How do I change Saxon's standard error output stream in Java?

Tags: java, stream, saxon

I'm using Saxon 9 to perform XSL transforms in Java.  If there is an error during the transform, Saxon directs the output to the standard error stream of the JVM in which it is running.  My Java application has a logging mechanism for standard output and errors.  How do I force Saxon to use my error output stream rather than the JVM default error output stream?

Answer (score 5):

Saxon diverts errors to a [javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/ErrorListener.html) object. Initially there's a default one of these objects that writes exceptions to stderr, but you can easily create a new ErrorListener object and implement its `warning`, `error`, and `fatalError` methods, to send them to your custom logging mechanism.

How to set the new ErrorListener depends on [whether you are using the JAXP interface or the s9api interface](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/embedding.xml). For the JAXP interface you can call `setErrorListener` on the Transformer object. For the s9api interface there's a `setErrorListener` method on the Configuration object you can supply when creating the Processor, or on the XsltCompiler object, or on the XsltTransformer object. There's several of them around, anyway.

Something like this (s9api):

```
final PrintStream logFile =
    new java.io.PrintStream("errorlog.txt"); // for example

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setErrorListener(new ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        exception.printStackTrace(logFile); // or wherever
    }

    @Override
    public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        exception.printStackTrace(logFile);
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        exception.printStackTrace(logFile);
    }
});
Processor proc = new Processor(configuration);
...
```

If you don't want to use stderr for anything in the program though, it might be better to just redirect it program-wide using [System.setErr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29):

```
System.setErr(new java.io.PrintStream("errorlog.txt"));
```

It takes a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) object, which you can potentially wrap around any type of output/stream, so I'm sure it can work for your custom logging mechanism.